# special characters inserted in https json return string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, curl, https, nginx

When using curl to get the JSON string, I am getting some strange characters in my json string. those characters are "0d 0a 32 30 30 30 0d 0a" in HEX, they are repeated several times in the returned JSON string.  I am using https, rails server with Nginx.  However if I use rails server with another web server such as Webrick, I don't have such issue.

***curl --trace output***

```
1c60: 6c 65 66 74 5f 63 6f 72 6e 65 72 22 3a 6e 75 6c left_corner":nul
1c70: 6c 2c 22 6c 65 0d 0a 32 30 30 30 0d 0a 66 74 5f l,"le..2000..ft_
1c80: 68 65 69 67 68 74 22 3a 6e 75 6c 6c 2c 22 72 69 height":null,"ri
```

***curl --trace-ascii output***

```
1c46: eft_leg_child_size":null,"left_corner":null,"le
1c77: 2000
1c7d: ft_height":null,
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the response have a Transfer-Encoding: [chunked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) header?  That looks like it may be a chunk length tag.

Comment: it does have "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" in the response header

Comment: What client are you using?  http/1.1 clients are required to handle chunked encoding.